# How can I find out if a file-like object performs newline translation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a [library](https://github.com/aptiko/textbisect) that does some kind of binary search in a seekable open file that it receives as an argument.

The file must have been opened with `open(..., newline="\n")`, otherwise `.seek()` and `.tell()` might not work properly if there's newline translation.

The README of the library does make this thing clear, but still it's easy to miss. I missed it myself and I was wondering why things aren't working properly. I'd therefore like to make the library raise an error or at least a warning if it receives a file-like object that performs text translation. Is it possible to make this check?

Comment: "file-like" is a somewhat vague term, and there's no documented way I know of to detect if whatever is passed as an argument even supports something like a `newline` argument. That said, you may be able to automatically reconfigure the most likely type of argument received via the [`io.TextIOWrapper.reconfigure()`]https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper.reconfigure() method so it's in the mode required—and doing that is successful, there wouldn't be a need to raise an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways around this. One is Python 3.7's [io.TextIOWrapper.reconfigure()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper.reconfigure) (thanks @martineau!).

The second one is to make some tests to see whether `seek`/`tell` work as expected. A simple but inefficient way to do it is this:

```
from io import SEEK_END


def has_newlines_translated(f):
    f.seek(0)
    file_size_1 = len(f.read())
    file_size_2 = f.seek(0, SEEK_END) - 1
    return file_size_1 != file_size_2
```

It may be possible to do it more efficiently by reading character by character (with `f.read(1)`) until past the first newline and playing with `seek()`/`tell()` to see whether results are consistent, but it's tricky and it wouldn't work in all cases (e.g. if the first newline is a lone `\n` whereas other newlines are `\r\n`).